# Finding a recursive formula for the number of ways to represent a vector in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as a sum of vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

Let $z=a+bi$, where $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers. I need to count how many ways are there to represent $z$ as
$$z=\sum\limits_{j}a_j+b_ji$$, where $\forall j \ \ a_j\not=0$ or $b_j\not=0$. $a_j$ and $b_j$ are non-negative integers.

Edit: I have found that the result is [OEIS A223544](http://oeis.org/A223544):
$$\begin{cases}T(n,1) = n - 1 \\
T(n,k) = T(n,k-1) + n\end{cases}$$
 through computation. However, I still do not have a proof for this formula.

Comment: Are $a_j$ and $b_j$ supposed to be nonnegative integers, too? And why do you talk of complex numbers when all you care about are vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: $a_j$ and $b_j$ are integers and $\forall j$ at least one of them is nonnegative. Well, techincally $z$ is a complex number, but yes, I should've phrased it better. I'll edit this post now.

Comment: "At least one is nonnegative" does not suffice to achieve a finite answer. For example, you can add as many $-1+i$s as you wish as long as you balance them out with $1-i$s. Something tells me you want nonnegative integers.

Comment: My mistake indeed. I need nonnegative integers, with at least one in each pair being positive _(otherwise $0+0i$ would lead to infinity)_

Comment: IIRC, the keyword for this are "vector compositions" or "vector partitions" (depending on whether the order of the $j$ matters). Not sure if this helps count them, though....

Comment: How do the $n$ and $k$ in the OEIS formula relate to your problem?